# Trouble with KeyListener in animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, compiler-errors, keylistener

I am trying to make a simple animation using `ActionListener` and `KeyListener` 
    that will take in keyboard inputs, namely the arrow keys.
    The problem is the program is not compiling with `KeyListener`. Can someone please
    shed some light on why and possibly provide help with a solution. 
    Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Planegame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{   //^^ this line is giving me trouble^^^^

Timer tim = new Timer(20, this);
int x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0;
public Planegame()
{
    tim.start();         //this will start my animation
    addKeyListener(this);   // will activate the keylistner to watch key press   
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);  //disables shift and tab key
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)     
{
    x = x + 10;  //velX 
    y = y + velY;
    repaint();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode()==38) 
    {
        velY = 1;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==40)
    {
        velY = -1;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==32)   //booster power
    {
        velX = 3;
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyReleased(keyEvent e) {}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PlaneGame zed = new PlaneGame();
    JFrame k = new JFrame();
    k.setTitle("game");
    k.setSize(600,400);
    k.setVisible(true);
    k.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    k.add(zed);
}
}
```

Comment: BTW - `Planegame` should also `@Override .. getPreferredSize()` to return 600x400.  Then instead of `k.setSize(600,400);`, simply add the plane game and `k.pack()`.  Easy done.  The game is exactly the right size, and we neither know nor care how big the frame is, but simply that it is *the right size* needed to display the content.

Comment: `e.getKeyCode()==32`  Don't use magic numbers. The magic might break on another JVM, or the next version.  There are [constants defined for key codes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#field.summary) (which work reliably across all JVMs).

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in the declaration of `keyReleased` method...

```
public void keyReleased(keyEvent e) {
```

Remember, Java is case sensitive, it should be...

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
```

Note the uppercase `K` in `KeyEvent`

You wish to consider using the `@Override` annotation on methods that you think you are overriding, this will alert you when you've made a mistake of some kind, for example

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
```

There's also no reason why `paintComponent` should be `public`, you never want some one outside of your component to call it

As always, I'd advise using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` as they provide better control over the level of focus your component needs to be able to trigger a key event

Comment: Thank you, wow that was a really basic error. Next time i will pay better attention. Up vote for you ^^^^

Comment: @AndrewThompson Agreed, that would have at least raised another compiler error ;)